# How can I use consecutive numbers in an Ex-style substitute command?

Tags: ex-mode, replace, variables, global-command

For example, let's say I want to put a number before every line that starts with the word "Do".  The command would look something like `:%s/^(Do )/1. \1/`, but what can I do so it will apply numbers consecutively instead of the same number each time?

Note that I'm well aware of the numerous ways to do this using macros and Ctrl-A, but for use in more complicated Ex-mode commands I would like to know the answer to exactly the title question.

For another example where a macro approach wouldn't be so easy, let's say I want to append a number to all instances of the word "Section", and have them consecutively numbered but restarting the count after each line that starts "Chapter".  An Ex-mode command that can *almost* do this, save for actually incrementing the number to be added, is:

`:g/^Chapter/;/^Chapter/-s/Section\zs/ 1/g`

You can see that an easy method of incrementing numbers in the Ex-mode substitute command could be very useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This command does what you want:

```
:let i = 1|g/^Do/s/^/\=i/|let i = i + 1
```

Explanation…

- `let i = 1` initializes counter `i`,
- `g/^Do/s/^/\=i/` prepends `i` to each line starting with `Do`,
- `let i = i + 1` increments `i`.

The trick is that the incrementation happens before the next substitution.

--- edit ---

If we used a single substitution, the counter would only be incremented once, after everything is done.

Since we are performing multiple substitutions — one for each matching line — instead of a single one, the counter is correctly incremented before the next substitution.

Comment: How can you put a dot after the number? `\=i. ` is an invalid expression.

Comment: @DavidConrad, `.` becomes a concatenate operator in the `\=` expression.  So `s//\=i . '. '/` will append `'. '`  Check out `:help expression-syntax`.

Comment: incrementation happens after the substitution

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, oops I accidentally a word.